# TSQL Last Record Efficiency Cursor, SubQuery, or CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, performance

Consider the following query...

```
SELECT
     *
    ,CAST(
            (CurrentSampleDateTime - PreviousSampleDateTime) AS FLOAT
        ) * 24.0 * 60.0 AS DeltaMinutes
FROM    
(   
    SELECT
         C.SampleDateTime AS CurrentSampleDateTime
        ,C.Location
        ,C.CurrentValue
        ,(
            SELECT TOP 1 
                Previous.SampleDateTime
            FROM Samples AS Previous
            WHERE 
                    Previous.Location = C.Location
                AND Previous.SampleDateTime < C.SampleDateTime
            ORDER BY Previous.SampleDateTime DESC       
        ) AS PreviousSampleDateTime
    FROM Samples AS C
) AS TempResults
```

Assuming all things being equal such as indexing, etc is this the most efficient way of achieving the above results?  That is using a SubQuery to retrieve the last record?

Would I be better off creating a cursor that orders by Location, SampleDateTime and setting up variables for CurrentSampleDateTime and PreviousSampleDateTime...setting the Previous to the Current at the bottom of the while loop?

I'm not very good with CTE's is this something that could be accomplished more efficiently with a CTE?  If so what would that look like?

I'm likely going to have to retrieve PreviousValue along with Previous SampleDateTime in order to get an average of the two.  Does that change the results any.

Long story short what is the best/most efficient way of holding onto the values of a previous record if you need to use those values in calculations on the current record?

----UPDATE
I should note that I have a clustered index on Location, SampleDateTime, CurrentValue so maybe that is what is affecting the results more than anything.

with 5,591,571 records my query (the one above) on average takes 3 mins and 20 seconds

The CTE that Joachim Isaksson below on average is taking 5 mins and 15 secs.

Maybe it's taking longer because it's not using the clustered index but is using the rownumber for the joins?

I started testing the cursor method but it's already at 10 minutes...so no go on that one.

I'll give it a day or so but think I will accept the CTE answer provided by Joachim Isaksson just because I found a new method of getting the last row.

Can anyone concur that it's the index on Location, SampleDateTime, CurrentValue that is making the subquery method faster?

I don't have SQL Server 2012 so can't test the LEAD/LAG method.  I'd bet that would be quicker than anything I've tried assuming Microsoft implemented that efficiently.  Probably just have to swap a pointer to a memory reference at the end of each row.

Comment: I'd at least use `MIN` instead of `TOP 1 x... ORDER BY x` (unless the construct is for sorting null first)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson But he needs `MAX`

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Lamak Yes, `MAX` would make sense, just translating the current query which (probably erroneously) does `MIN`.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 but I think it is relevant for SQL 2005 and greater.  CTE's were introduced in 2005 and why I didn't tag a specific SQL Server Version.

Comment: I asked because if using 2012 you'd have access to `LEAD` and `LAG`.

Comment: Just edited question slightly.  The inner query should be ordered by datetime desc to get the last SampleDateTime for a given location based on the current records SampleDateTime.  It's basically to do a integration (sum of values below the curve) using Change In Time (DeltaMinutes) and will be adding AverageValue between the previous and current values.

Comment: @GoatCO +1 Yes, `LAG` would get rid of the join and would likely speed things up further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use the LAG window function that retrieves the value of the specified column from the previous row. It returns null if there is no previous row.

```
SELECT 
 a.*,
 CAST((a.SampleDateTime - LAG(a.SampleDateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY a.location ORDER BY a.SampleDateTime ASC)) AS FLOAT) 
             * 24.0 * 60.0 AS DeltaMinutes
FROM samples a
ORDER BY
 a.location,
 a.SampleDateTime
```

You'd have to run some tests to see if it's faster. If you're not using SQL Server 2012 then at least this may give others an idea of how it can be done with 2012. I like @Joachim Isaksson 's answer using a CTE with a Row_Number()/Partition By for 2008 and 2005.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/97abb/4/0)

Have you considered creating a temp table to use instead of a CTE or subquery? You can create indexes on the temp table that are more suited for the join on RowNumber.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (
  RowNumber INT,
  Location INT,
  SampleDateTime DATETIME,
  CurrentValue INT)
;

INSERT INTO #tmp
 SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Location 
                           ORDER BY SampleDateTime DESC) rn,
  Location,
  SampleDateTime,
  CurrentValue
 FROM Samples
;

CREATE INDEX idx_location_row ON #tmp(Location,RowNumber) INCLUDE (SampleDateTime,CurrentValue);

SELECT 
 a.Location,
 a.SampleDateTime,
 a.CurrentValue,
 CAST((a.SampleDateTime - b.SampleDateTime) AS FLOAT) * 24.0 * 60.0 AS DeltaMinutes
FROM #tmp a
LEFT JOIN #tmp b ON 
 a.Location = b.Location 
 AND b.RowNumber = a.RowNumber +1  
ORDER BY
 a.Location, 
 a.SampleDateTime
```

[SQL Fiddle #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97abb/11)

Comment: 4:10 mins for my result set...faster than the CTE but still slower than my original.  Thanks for extra info about indexes on temp tables.  I'm guessing if I removed my current index the temp table method would be faster than mine and sorry I can't test the LEAD/LAG method on my 2008 server.

Comment: Did you try with the "ORDER BY" or without? If you don't need the ORDER BY, then you can take that out of the final select since you are dealing with a large data set and ordering eats up so much CPU. This may speed things up a bit. You could also play around with creating a CLUSTERED index on the temp table on location, rownumber, sampleDateTime, currentValue instead of the regular index with the include.

Comment: Actually got yours down to 3:51 by changing the order by to "ORDER BY Location, SampleDateTime DESC"...basically put Location in front of it.  I assume it increased performance because that's what the original index is defined on.

Comment: Since yours was faster than the CTE route and you introduced a new option that I hadn't considered I'm going to accept yours.  Anyway I can accept both?

Answer (score 1):

As always, testing with your real data is king.

Here's a CTE version that shows the samples for each location with time deltas from the previous sample. It uses `OVER` ranking, which usually does well in comparison to subqueries for solving the same problem.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Location 
                               ORDER BY SampleDateTime DESC) rn
  FROM Samples
)
SELECT a.*,CAST((a.SampleDateTime - b.SampleDateTime) AS FLOAT) 
                 * 24.0 * 60.0 AS DeltaMinutes
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b ON a.Location = b.Location AND b.rn = a.rn +1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/97abb/3).

Comment: In your example with 5 inserts into the table...there should be 5 records in the result not 3.  DeltaMinutes will be null for the very first entry of each location as it won't have a previous sample date time.  Say I have one location that get's a sampled 7 times a week the result set should have 7 records for that location.  I'm not reducing/condensing the record set but instead just adding calculated information based on current record and previous record.

Comment: Execute my query in your SQLFiddle example to see the results I am looking for.  Also not necessarily a question as how to convert SQL to CTE although it would be nice...but more importantly which method, sub query, cursor, cte is going to give me optimal performance.  My current query is very slow.

Comment: @DanP The ranking functions (ROW_NUMBER/PARTITION in this case) are usually very  fast at analyzing sequences of events for multiple data points (locations). I can't speak for your data set or indexing, but I find them hard to beat.

Comment: yes new fiddle retrieves results and result set is the same as my original query but now for which one has better performance and would I be better off using a cursor with temp variables for this solution?

Comment: @DanP I can't think of a way of doing it with a cursor without increasing time complexity which would hurt for large data sets, but someone else might.